# mysql convert String to datetime format

Tags: mysql

In MySQL trying to convert string to date time format, but its returning the null value.

What it the correct way to convert below string to datetime format?

```
> select STR_TO_DATE('8/16/18 7:00 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %r');
+-------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('8/16/18 7:00 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %r')   |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta match the format, %r doesn't match 7:00 PM

From: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

```
%r = Time in 12 hour AM or PM format (hh:mm:ss AM/PM)
```

As you can see, expects a two digit hour, and seconds, which you don't have.

You also don't match the year %Y expects a four digit Year... so i changed it to %y

Try like this.

```sql
select STR_TO_DATE('8/16/18 7:00 PM', '%c/%e/%y %l:%i %p');
```